# How to implement logout functionality in android using facebook login

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook login in my android app. I am using access token and access expire for this app. But what code should I use for logout this app. I want to add a logout button, If I click on this, logout functionality should work. My login button code is:

```
btnfblogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bfb);
btnfblogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
 // button logout
 try {
  fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
  updateButtonImage();
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
} else {
 // button Login
 fb.authorize(Login.this, new String[] { "email" },
   new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(Login.this, "fbError",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(Login.this, "OnError",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Editor editor = sp.edit();
     editor.putString("access_token",
       fb.getAccessToken());
     editor.putLong("access_expires",
       fb.getAccessExpires());
     editor.commit();
     updateButtonImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Oncancel",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   });

 }
}
});
```

I want to use logout functionality on different activity. I am using first activity for login and want to logout from fourth activity.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this functionality for logout `facebook sdk 3.x`

```
    if (fb_session != null && fb_session.isOpened()) {                            
         fb_session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();                 
     }
```

in Old sdk try this

```
   if( mFb.isSessionValid() ) {                                  
       mFb.logout(getApplicationContext());
       SessionStore.clear(getApplicationContext());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code..

Use this code where you need to logout from facebook.This will clear all facebook information. And then redirect the control to main activity (or) some other.

```
 private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on particular button click event just put the following line

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

this will logout from the facebook and back to your main activity or where you want.